# How to check order of Array element in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, is there any easy way to check Order of element in Array? For example I have a document like this:

```js
{
    _id: 1,
    tags: ["mongodb", "rethinkdb", "couchbase", "others"]
}
```

I would like to check in **tags** field if `mongodb` come before `rethinkdb` or not(lets see in array element, mongodb=0, rethinkdb=1 index, so mongodb come first and our case match.)? 
but if there is another document (like below) where `rethinkdb` comes before `mongodb`,It case does not match.

```js
{
  _id: 2,
  tags: ["rethinkdb", "mongodb", "couchbase"]
 }
```

Here mongodb(1) comes after rethinkdb(0) so our case does not match.

Comment: Not too sure what you actually mean. What is your actual use case? How do you want to compare this? Against one or many documents?

Comment: There can be many documents,  I have to find if they are properly ordered in array or not. we can check index/position of array, but I don't have idea how can I get position.

Comment: Try and edit your question to expand on that idea. I still have no idea how you expect to compare one document to another. As in how do you know you are comparing document 1 to document 2 etc. So you need to be more descriptive about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have edited, I hope it is quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really as clear as you think it is, and thus why there are several ways to answer it:

If you are looking just to find out if a document has "mongodb" as the first element of the array then you just issue a query like this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "tags.0": "mongodb" })
```

And that will return only the documents that match the given value at the specified index position using "dot notation".

If you actually expect to match if an array is in an "expected order" then you can get some help from the aggregation pipeline and set operators that are available and other features in MongoDB 2.6:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {        
        "$_id": "$$ROOT",
        "matched": { "$setEquals": [ 
            "$tags", 
           ["mongodb", "rethinkdb", "couchbase", "others"]
        ]}
    }},
    { "$match": { "matched": true }}
])
```

Or if your want is to make sure that the "mongodb" value comes before the "rethinkdb" value, then you will need to evaluate in JavaScript with mapReduce, or something equally not nice like the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator:

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$where": function() {
        return this.tags.indexOf("mongodb") < this.tags.indexOf("rethinkdb");
    }
})
```

Comment: How can we make sure the order of elements of both arrays are identical along with the distinct elements? Because setEquals only matches the distinct elements. A1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], A2: ['b', 'a', 'c'] => false(order doesn't match), A1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], A2: ['a', 'b', 'c'] => true(order and element both matches). A1: ['a', 'b', 'c'], A2: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], => false(order matches, elements don't). Thanks in advance!